# How to prove if function is onto and one to one on set $A \to B$ then inverse function maps $B \to A $?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Consider $f:A \to B$. If $f$ is one-one and onto, how to prove $f^{-1}$ maps $B\to A$ with function definitions.

Comment: By clarifying what $f^{-1}$ ought to be, and then show that it fulfills the conditions that we require of a function $B\to A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse $f^{-1}$ is always a map from $B$ to $A$. For any function, or any relation in general, $f^{-1}=\{(y,x):y\in B\wedge x\in A \wedge f(x)=y\}$. Your one-one condition guarantees that $f^{-1}$ is again a function, without it cannot be one.